# How to hide description area of CBCGPPropList?

Tags: c++, uitableview, mfc, controls, cwnd

Now I am using CBCGPPropList of CBCGToolBar within MFC, but I don't know how to add a CBCGPGridCtrl into CBCGPPropList, so I have to leave it outside. But the description area looks ugly between them:   :(

[image]

**Is there any way to add a Table-like widget into CBCGPPropList or can I just hide the description area of CBCGPPropList?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be `CBCGPPropList::EnableDescriptionArea(FALSE)` helps you?

Comment: Great! Thank you! This problem is really a headache for me!

Comment: ...As all of BCG library stuff for me too :D Their only documentation is the very ugly code.